# Segue to View Controller based on indentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a few view controllers with the same classes.

How can I differentiate between them when segueing to a specific one?

Normally I would use this code to do it, but this only works when there is a single instance of the class:

```
SecondViewController *secondview = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:secondview animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi,
you have just to set the segues in the storyboard. What's the problem?
I have created an app which use the same class for 3 view controllers, but i just set the segues in the storyboard..

Comment: I want to do it without the storyboard. I want to do it within the code based on conditions

Comment: oh sorry, i wrote an answer

Comment: If you want to do it without a storyboard, then that's not a segue. Segues are specific to transitions between controllers in a storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these option:

-Use storyboard and so, use segues;

-Use storyboard and use:

```
ExploreViewController *ev = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];
```

-Don't use storyboard and so you have just to set the nib name in "**initWithNibName**" in according of the viewcontrollers which you want show.